# In SSIS, How to convert unicode datatype to excel column?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I am working on SSIS Package to export the output data to Excel file. ( Excel Destination ).

I am running into conversion error.

> Error Description : cannot convert between Unicode and non-Unicode string data types

**Input Column Details**

```
ColumnA ([DT_TEXT])
ColumnB ([DT_STR],200)
```

**Data Conversion Output Column Details**

```
ColumnA ([DT_TEXT])
ColumnB ([DT_WSTR],255)
```

How to convert Unicode datatype to excel column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using Derived Column Transformation

Add a derived column with the following expression

```
(DT_WSTR,255)[ColumnB]
```

When if fails you can use the Error Output to check the bad values causing the exception

## Using Data Conversion Transformation

You can also achieve this using a Data Conversion transformation component. Just select the ColumnB as input and choose to convert to `DT_WSTR` data type with length = 255

## Using Script Component

You just have to select ColumnB as Input column, add an Output column `outColumnB` of type `DT_WSTR` and length = 255. And just assign the input column to the output column inside the script.

```
Row.outColumnB = Row.ColumnB
```

---

## Update 1 - Excel data types

Based on the following official documentation:

- [Import data from Excel or export data to Excel with SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-from-excel-with-ssis?view=sql-server-2017#issues-types)

> The Excel driver recognizes only a limited set of data types. For example, all numeric columns are interpreted as doubles (DT_R8), and all string columns (other than memo columns) are interpreted as 255-character Unicode strings (DT_WSTR). SSIS maps the Excel data types as follows:
>
> - Numeric - double-precision float (DT_R8)
> - Currency - currency (DT_CY)
> - Boolean - Boolean (DT_BOOL)
> - Date/time - datetime (DT_DATE)
> - String - Unicode string, length 255 (DT_WSTR)
> - Memo - Unicode text stream (DT_NTEXT)

Comment: I am facing issue with this column ..  ColumnA, DataType : DT_TEXT, Length : 0

Comment: Error: 0xC002F445 at Data Flow Task, Excel Destination [60]: An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "COLUMNA" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT".
Error: 0xC0202025 at Data Flow Task, Excel Destination [60]: Cannot create an OLE DB accessor. Verify that the column metadata is valid.

Comment: I will search on that and give you a reply in a while

Comment: This error happens, when i keep the Header only template. Template excel sheet does not have any records to it. In an assumption, if i have existing row of record. I am not facing this error

Comment: And other problem is, every time job run .. we expect completely new set of record. At this moment, new record is appended.

Comment: @goofyui concerning the data types check my answer update, and the link i added there are many helpful information about Excel Destination. Concerning other issues they should be posted in seperate posts with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use data conversion tool and convert DT_WSTR to DT_STR.Check this:

- [Import Excel unicode data with SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1393/import-excel-unicode-data-with-sql-server-integration-services/)

Answer (score 0):

DT_TEXT and DT_STR from input are non-unicode and excel inputs are all unicode so your conversion is not unicode to non-unicode but non-unicode to unicode.

All your Data Conversion Output Columns (excel input) should be DT_NTEXT and DT_WSTR then.

Answer (score 0):

To convert from unicode dt_wstr to float , first use a data conversion step to convert from dt_wstr to str (dt_str) and then change to double precision float.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).